# enabling hourly data in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have two view/profiles linked to my google analytics account. I want to fetch the hourly data for the current day, ie

start date:today

end date: today

with a few filters and dimensions.
Now I am getting the response for one view that means it is possible in google analytics, however for the other view its showing all the values as 0- this applies both to the gui and the api.
Can anyone suggest me how to enable it for the other view as well?

Comment: Google Analytics is real time for tracking but you can't say that give accuracy on time based punctual

Comment: what dimensions you used to fetch hourly data please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Google Analytics needs some processing time. It might be that some data appears immediately, especially on small accounts, but it's not guaranteed and not a thing you can "enable" or count on.

Updated: Okay, that was a dumb answer. Still, there is a processing latency event in GA Premium. It is possible to get realtime data, but that's a different API with limited data (the core reporting API might return data, but no guarantees for that).

But I admit, since your problem is that you do not get data for the whole day yor have a different problem. But with a premium account you should be able to contact your account manager/technical support.

Comment: mine is a premium account, and for the app i am geting data after each hour but for the site i am not getting the data for the whole day. Even the real time data is available for the current moment for both the views.

Comment: Realtime data is a different AP (and sorry for me making assumptions).

Comment: so there is no way to get hourly data for the current day, not even for past two hours?

Comment: yeah for real time data i am using the google's real time api's beta version, but they give the data at te moment. I was interested in data till now since 00:00, i.e. like i said for the current day.